# Проблема с yii2

Tags: apache, .htaccess, php, yii, ubuntu

Здравствуйте, начал изучать yii2, с установкой проблем нет. Позже встретил следующую проблему.

Значит фронтенд расположен здесь http://yiinew.loc/frontend/web/ - работает

Страничка с блогом расположена здесь http://yiinew.loc/frontend/web/blog/ - получаю ошибку:

**Not Found**
The requested URL /home/dogmar/Dropbox/www/yiinew/frontend/web/index.php was not found on this server. (Путь файла правильный)

Но работает если открыть так http://yiinew.loc/frontend/web/index.php/blog/

**Конфиг urlManager:**

```
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'enableStrictParsing' => true,
        'showScriptName' => true,
        'suffix' => '/',
```

**/home/dogmar/Dropbox/www/yiinew/frontend/web/.htaccess**

```
# Mod_Autoindex
<IfModule mod_autoindex.c>
  # Запрещаем просмотр содержимого папок
  Options -Indexes
</IfModule>

# Mod_Rewrite
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymlinks
  # Включаем mod_rewrite
  RewriteEngine On

  # Если это папка или файл, открываем её/его
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  # В противном случае перенаправляем на index.php
  RewriteRule . index.php
</IfModule>
```

Вопрос: Почему не работает .htaccess?

---

Решение RewriteRule . /frontend/web/index.php

Answer (score 2):

Хороший вопрос, строит переоткрыть.

Вы в своем проекте используете шаблон [advanced](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/tree/master/apps/advanced).
Этот шаблон предполагает несколько точек входа (несколько приложений).
В простейшем случае: основная часть (frontend), и админка (backend).

Если приложение разворачивается на выделенном сервере, то на каждую точку нужно настраивать отдельный виртуальный хост.
Чтобы по адресу `host.com` открывалась папка `/frontend/web`, а по `admin.host.com` - `/backend/web`.
Для локальной разработки на своем компьютере все тоже самое.

Для хостинга, в большинстве случаев такая настройка либо недоступна, либо можно указать только одну точку входа.
Для хостингов есть [неплохое решение](http://aaronfrancis.com/blog/2014/1/9/hosting-an-advanced-yii2-application-on-heroku) через `.htaccess`.
`frontend` будет доступен по адресу `host.com`, а `backend` - `host.com/admin`.

Открывать для веб-сервера корневую папку приложения не безопасно.